# Process behaviour after receiving a SIGSEGV signal?

Tags: c, linux, unix

We recently learned about signals in UNIX our OS class. We use C to access the unix API.

A class mate was fooling around with dereferencing invalid pointers (to unallocated memory or null pointers) and then handling the resulting SIGSEGV signal. He had a code block that went something like this:

```
int* p;
int i = 0;
for (; i < 10; i++){
    printf("Iteration %d\n", i);
    p = i;
    int n = *p;
}
```

Then he had a simple signal handler that would simply print the signal number. What ended up happening was that the program would repeatedly print out that it had received a signal with the number 11 - a SIGSEGV signal and wouldn't ever exit the loop. Our professor found this behaviour to be odd and said he'd look into it.

From a search I did on the internet the behaviour does not seem to be at all odd, as the program is supposed to perform the offending instruction again after the signal it receives is handled in the case of a SIGSEGV. However this behaviour seems not to be documented anywhere in any of the official UNIX or LINUX documentation. Can any of you point me in the general direction of documentation regarding this type of behaviour?

EDIT:

The signal handler went something like this:

```
void signal_handler(int signo)
{
printf("%d\n", signo);
}
```

Redirecting console output to a file generated something like this:

```
Iteration 0
11
11
11
11
11
... (only stopped if we sent it a SIGINT)
```

Comment: If you catch the signal, then the loop will just continue after the handler has finished. So it will raise in the next signal. There is no magic in that. I do not see why or how that should be documented. It is just how a program works. One thing after another. Until it exists or is killed.

Comment: Well according to my professor he expected the program to skip to the next instruction after the signal was handled. Instead it kept repeating the offending instruction, thus causing a new signal, and so on indefinitely.

Comment: You sure it is the same instruction it keeps repeating? I'd say it is the same instruction _in the next iteration of the loop_.

Comment: No, it is the same instruction that keeps repeating, we checked that. It printed the signal thousands of times and a simple write to the STDIN before the int n = *p; line would only print once when the program began.

Comment: Sorry, no idea currently. Sounds strange. Certainly the instruction should _not_ get repeated. Where do you have that idea from if not from some documentation?

Comment: Ah darn, not paying attention. Of course it repeats the same instruction. Why shouldn't it? The execution pointer still stands at the same location. Nothing increments it. Why should it suddenly progress somewhere else? So this is not a feature, it is more _the lack of a feature_. You cannot really document something that is not there...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the documentation you found says the response of the OS on returning from a SIGSEGV is undefined. Specifically for this instance it means that the relevant library standards don't define where it should resume but leave it to the exact details of the machine it's running on.

From memory X86 derived machines will restart the faulting instruction. However, Other processors skip that instruction an continue with the next. In general neither method is that useful as they both can create very weird behaviours.

As you might guess from this exactly what is done usually depends on the processor you're running on. For a particular processor the page fault response (and other faults) are all defined precisely this includes exactly what will happen if you do an 'Return' instruction on the fault stack frame.

In general, for a portable program, the only safe thing to do in a SIGSEGV handler is to exit the program. It is, however, possibly to use setjmp/longjmp if you're very, very careful about not trapping the signal during library calls or similar.

Comment: I may have misunderstood what you wrote. But it doesn't seem correct to me. Catching and handling a SIGSEGV are valid and is often used to perform certain memory management operations. And it is well defined. The faulting instruction is restarted after the handler is called. In this case the signal handler should do something to ensure the restarted instruction does not fault again (e.g. mapping in a new page to make the memory access valid or exiting the process). If the signal handler does not do this then the instruction will repeatedly fault - exactly what the questioner is seeing.

Comment: For a reference on the signal handler return semantics see the "sigreturn" man page. Specifically: "It restores the process's signal mask, switches stacks, and restores the process's context...so that the process resumes execution at the point where it was interrupted by the signal."

Comment: Mapping and remapping memory is a good use-case for 'sigreturn'.  But the sigreturn function is a BSD derived extension to the sigaction standards. It is IMO a good candidate for future inclusion in the XOPEN standards but isn't there yet. Even so it's portability may be good enough for a lot of situations. For a very good reference as to what's actually in the standard go see: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/ for everybody else's manpages you can look at https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi